# Secure API keys. Environment variables. Proper way to deploy securing keys

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, dotenv

I have a project that I built with Angular. I want to host it but it makes calls to an API with an API KEY. From my understanding, there is no way to secure your keys from the client. I have been researching how to accomplish this, but I cannot find anything useful.

I want to deploy this small app to Heroku to learn how to do this. In my environment.ts file Should I replace the values with the variables in the .env file, build the application, then just add the key/value pairs to Heroku's Config Vars?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two environment files. One for development and one for production:

environment.dev.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  API_KEY: "XXX"
};
```

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY
};
```

Define these files in angular.cli.json:

```
"environments": {
  "dev": "environment.dev.ts",
  "prod": "environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Add `--prod` to `postinstall` script for Heroku deploys in package.json:

```
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
```

And finally, add Config Vars in Heroku dashboard or using heroku-cli:

```
heroku config:set API_KEY=PROD_XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a backend for the API call? Your server could function as a middleman to authenticate your user and only make API calls your code intended to make. It is not clear what kind of API is used in your app but it can be dangerous to expose API keys not intended for public use (unlike Firebase API keys which are meant to be public).

Anyway, you should never store credentials hard-coded or commited to repository through configuration files. The basic steps are:

1. Create a `.env` file in your project root and add it to `.gitignore`. This is for **local** development.
2. Set **production** [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) in Heroku  CLI or Dashboard.
3. Update `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  ...rest,
  exampleApiKey: process.env.EXAMPLE_API_KEY,
};
```